# SVG GaussianBlur quality

Tags: d3.js, svg, graphics, html-rendering, gaussianblur

I am showing a SVG map with the coastline drawn with a blurry effect as shown on this image:

[image]

I am using a simple `feGaussianBlur` filter to draw the coastline below the land polygons:

```
<filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4">
</feGaussianBlur></filter>
```

The result is satisfying on the north coast. However, some rectangular patterns appear in the red circle. This is due to the segmentation of the coast into several linear elements, whose blurry margins intersect.

Is there a way to fix this and have a 'nice' blurry effect everywhere?

I already tried `color-interpolation-filters=sRGB` and `image-rendering=optimizeQuality` without any success.

FYI, the demo map is [here](https://eurostat.github.io/Nuts2json/examples/overview.html) with [the source code](https://github.com/eurostat/Nuts2json/blob/gh-pages/examples/overview.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I think this because of the filter dimensions, the extended parts are cut. Try extending these boundaries:

```
<filter id="degenCodeNeon" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
```

The percentage uses objectBoundingBox, you could have also specified userSpaceOnUse. But first try this one.

Tried with x,y -250% and width/height 600%, seems to work. I suggest adding color matrix or component transfer filters as addition to completely reduce alpha to 0 below a certain threshold.

Comment: extending the box to something even larger gives the expected result: x="-100%" y="-100%" width="400%" height="400% Thanks !!!

Comment: Yes it does, please try to add feColorMatrix or componentTransfer filters to completely reduce alpha to 0 if below 0.2 etc. Because the burden will be much easier on your CPU, good luck with your project btw, nice map.